# Calculation of percentile and use it in formula

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, percentile

I'm trying to calculate percentile 95th and 5th for NDVI
I can put the 95th percentile and 5th percentile manually, but I want to do it automatically, that is, Google Earth Engine itself will extract the 95th and 5th percentile from ndvi and put the numbers in the desired formula.

When I run this code it gives me an error:

> SC: Layer error: parameter 'value' is required.

This is my code:

```
var start = "2022-01-01"
var end = "2022-12-30"

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1')
                  .filterDate(start, end)
                  .mean()
                  .clip(table);
var ndvi = dataset.select('NDVI')
.divide(10000);


var veg = ndvi.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.percentile([95]), table, 800)
print(veg)// prints 0.228500

var soil = ndvi.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.percentile([5]), table, 800)
print(soil)// prints 0.07244

var subtract = veg-soil
print(subtract)// prints **NaN**

var sc = (ndvi.subtract(soil)).divide(subtract);


var SCVis = {
  min: 12.685013010540562,
  max: 55.29669596981394,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};

Map.addLayer(sc, SCVis, 'SC');
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: first it doesnt show me subtract variable (NaN) and for sc give me this error SC: Layer error: Parameter 'value' is required.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification.

Comment: Your question body still does not contain the error message.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it :) Do you by chance have any approach that I could try on how to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```js
var subtract = veg-soil
```

should be changed to

```js
var subtract = veg.subtract(soil)
```

Using `-` (client-side operator) makes your `subtract` variable to be `NaN`. Interestingly, this is different to what you get if you use `+`: a more obviously incorrect result, as seen in the example provided below (recommended reading):

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging#avoid-mixing

```js
// Don't mix EE objects and JavaScript objects:
var image = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
var nonsense = image + 2;

// You can print this, but it's not what you were hoping for.
print(nonsense);
```